# How can I switch back my start up volume from an external to the internal drive?

Tags: macos, startup

By mistake my external drive has become the start up volume. How can I revert this?

Answer (score 2):

**change your startup disk**

1. Open System Preferences (click the top left Apple icon, click System Preferences
2. Click the 'Startup Disk' preference pane
3. Select the drive you want as startup disk

Another method should work as well:

- remove your drive and reboot